# Convert JSON Object To JSON Array

Tags: json, web-services, rest, jsonp, arrays

I'm having a problem.  My app won't load the resources from my web service because its format has been changed.

Before my web service is returning a JSON Array like this:

```
[{"productid":2,"sku":"SKU-2","productname":"SMART NEW","productdesc":"description","category":"default category","price":2000.1,"picture":"http://10.23.20.50:8080/msos-ws/images/products/smart.gif","remarks":"remarks"}]
```

Now its returning a JSON Object I guess:

```
{"product":[{"category":"default category","picture":"http://localhost:8080/msos-ws/images/products/smart.gif","price":"480.0","productdesc":"Dragon Flash Disk (Special)","productid":"7","productname":"Kingston 8GB","remarks":"remarks","sku":"SKU-7"}]}
```

Here's my code at backend:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Product> findAll() {
        return prodManager.getProducts();
}
```

I'm returning a List so it should be in array, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get is a key/value pair where key is

```
product
```

and the 1-element array is

```
[{"category":"default category","picture":"http://localhost:8080/msos-ws/images/products/smart.gif","price":"480.0","productdesc":"Dragon Flash Disk (Special)","productid":"7","productname":"Kingston 8GB","remarks":"remarks","sku":"SKU-7"}]
```

refer to www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html , take a look at following methods:

```
public java.lang.Object get(java.lang.String key)

public JSONObject put(java.lang.String key,
                  java.util.Collection value)
```

Modifying your app to load resources should be easy now :)